# Does the KeyDown KeySuppress cancel KeyUp event?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, keyboard-events

Let's say I've got this:

```
    private void txtAnalogValue_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            //Non-numeric key pressed => prevent this from being input into the Textbox
            e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

and this:

```
    private void txtAnalogValue_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            try
            {
                UpdateState(double.Parse(((TextBox)sender).Text));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ((TextBox)sender).Text = ioElement.StateVal.ToString("0.00");
            }
        }
    }
```

I know this code doesn't make a lot of sense, it's just test.
The question is: Will the e.SuppressKeyPress = true in KeyDown event have affect on KeyUp event, so the Enter key will not be accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `e.SuppressKeyPress = true` will just ignore the `Enter` key (it won't go to the next line and Text property of the textbox won't be changed) and e.Keycode will be visible in the `KeyUp`. Therefore suppressing the key in the `KeyDown` doesn't affect the `KeyUp` event and your code should work. The `UpdateState` will be called when you hit `Enter` button in the `TextBox`. You can try this code to check it:

```
        private void txtAnalogValue_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
            }
        }

        private void txtAnalogValue_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.A)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Up");
            }
        }
```